# Extracting Domain form multiple subdomain using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I've looked into many examples from stackoverflow, but none of the regex seems to work for me.

Below is my requirement,

I wanted to extract domain foe the following,

```
acd-test.example.com  // example.com
xyz-test.example.com  // example.com
```

I tried the below regex, but it is not working as expected

```
(^|^[^:]+:\/\/|[^\.]+\.)example\.com
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that without regex, just by using plain JS.

Use `split`, get the last two elements, the `join` them back.

```js
const extractDomain = (url) => url.split(".").slice(-2).join(".")

console.log(extractDomain("acd-test.example.com"))
console.log(extractDomain("xyz-test.example.com"))
console.log(extractDomain("qwe-test.more.com"))
```